# Standard deviation calculation outputing incorrectly

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of an array but my answer is returning as 0. I think the problem is stemming from the "count" getting messed up. The array I am receiving the data from is simply four numbers of 1,4,6,7. The code is outputting the answer as 0 but that is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
double mean(double *mydata, double N);
double standard_dev(double *mydata, double m, int N);

int main()
{
    int N(0);
    char filename [100];
    double m, stdev;
    double next;

    int count=0;
    cout<<"Enter name of file: ";
    cin>>filename;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename);
    while(myfile>>next)
    {
        count++;
    }

    N=count;
    double *mydata;
    mydata=new double[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        myfile>>mydata[i];
    }
    m =  mean(mydata, N);
    stdev = standard_dev(mydata, m, N);
    cout<<"The standard deviation is:" <<stdev<<endl;

    myfile.close();
    delete[] mydata;
    return 0;
}

double mean(double *mydata, double N)  
{
    double sum(0), m;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum +=mydata[i];
    }
    m=(sum/(double)N);
    return (m);
}
double standard_dev(double *mydata, double m, int N)
{
    double *mydata2= new double [N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        mydata2[i]= pow((mydata[i]-m),2);
    }
    double sum(0), S, X;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum+=mydata2[i];
    }
    X=sum/N;
    S=sqrt(X);
    return (S);
}
```

The code for the array containing the 4 numbers is just:
1
4
6
7
They are vertical in coding.

Comment: An online stddev is probably faster and just as accurate, and doesn't require the dynamic allocations (and memory leaks in your code). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods

Answer (score 2):

You are reading in the data wrong. First, you read in all the data to `next` to increment `count`. Then you try to read in the nonexistent data with you `for` loop. I recommend that you use `std::vector` to avoid the problem of dynamic memory allocation;

```
vector<double> mydata;
while(myfile>>next)
{
    mydata.push_back(next);
}
```

The other easiest solution is just to put the number of elements in the file. Ex:

File:

> 4 1 4 6 7

And read `N` from the file and use your for loop